# sending and getting parameters with jquery/coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

My situation is that i need to redirect user to specific page. page which has two inputs. normally they are blank and just wait to be filled. but when this redirection mentioned before is performed:

```
window.location.replace('new')
```

then i need those inputs to be filled. Question is how can i detec if i'm somewhere because of redirection. i was thinking about sending some special params and read them everytime i'm in this place with inputs. anybody knows how to send and read parameters with jquery/coffeescript?

Comment: Is the "referer" set on redirect? I don't remember.

Comment: Is it single-page application? Why do you use redirect?

Comment: How about something like `window.location.replace('new?arg1='+arg1+'&arg2='+arg2)`

Comment: its not single page app. i just need to get from one place to another with javascript

Comment: _"anybody knows how to send and read parameters with jquery/coffeescript"_ what about the solution by @JonathanLerner ? Is it acceptable or not?

Comment: yes, i believe it is acceptable, but i can't really 'accept' comment as answer on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like `window.location.replace('new?arg1='+arg1+'&arg2='+arg2)`